# Check object values with list of properties (reflection)

Tags: c#, linq, csv, reflection

I currently working on an dynamic upload module. The idea is to only define the file and the data contract for each new file. Currently I'm using reflection with 2 foreach, this is some heavy code to do this. As you can see in the code I have my object containing the csv file and 2 other lists. These two lists contains all the properties of the object where I would like to do data validation on.

```
var myCustomObjects = CsvSettings(new CsvReader(readFile, config)).GetRecords<MyCustomObject>();
var decimalProprties = GetPropertyNames<MyCustomObject>(typeof(decimal)).ToList();
var dateProprties = GetPropertyNames<MyCustomObject>(typeof(DateTime)).ToList();

foreach (var myCustomObject in myCustomObjects)
{
     foreach (var dateProperty in dateProprties)
     {
        var value = myCustomObject.GetType().GetProperty(dateProperty).GetValue(myCustomObject, null);
        Console.WriteLine(value); //code to check and report the value
     }
     Console.WriteLine(myCustomObject.Een + "|" + myCustomObject.Twee + "|" + myCustomObject.Drie);
}
```

How can I do this with an expression or even another way to have so less heavy code?

Comment: What do you mean by "heavy" code? This is reflection after all...

Comment: What is your main concern? Performance? Readability? Simplicity? ...?

Comment: Performance, If my csv has 9k lines and I check 10 properties it will run the reflection 90k times. I would rather see the reflection loaded 10 times and load it in the memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems fine as-is. You could perhaps simplify it a little by using a method that returns Key/Value pairs for all public properties of a certain type, like so (error handling elided for brevity):

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> PropertiesOfType<T>(object myObject)
{
    var properties = 
        from   property in myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
        where  property.PropertyType == typeof(T) && property.CanRead
        select new KeyValuePair<string, T>(property.Name, (T)property.GetValue(myObject));

    return properties;
}
```

Then you can avoid the additional call to `GetProperty()` in your inner loop:

```
foreach (var myCustomObject in myCustomObjects)
{
    foreach (var dateProperty in PropertiesOfType<DateTime>(myCustomObject))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dateProperty.Value);  // code to check and report the value.
    }
}
```

Also note that you don't seem to need the `.ToList()` calls.

Comment: The issue I have with this solution is having the reflection called so many time. I think because of this it will take more effort and time for the code to run.

Comment: @Freddy Have you timed it to determine if it's an issue? Reflection in C# is actually pretty fast.